# Ruby on Rails: How to use current_page helper to get subdirectories of a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a program where a user can create events, and there will be multiple events. So the events index page looks like "/events" on the browser, and it's subdirectory show pages looks like "/events/1 /events/2 ... etc".

In my layout page I am checking the current page in order to decide what background color the page will have. This is easy for the events index page; I just check if it is that page via the command:

```
if current_page?(events_path) ...
```

But I want to check if the current page is a specific 'show' page of the index (a standard scaffold generated page). How would I do that? This is my attempt, I am confused about how the routing would work in this case:

```
if current_page?(events_id_path) ...
```

Comment: You should try `action_name == "show"`. You can add another condition, with `controller_name == "YOURCONTROLLERNAME"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So simple, try the below code

```
if current_page?(event_path(@event))
```

Assuming you have `@event` defined in your controller.

**or**

```
if current_page?(controller: 'events', action: 'show', :id => id)
```

For more Info, see this [***API Doc***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F)

Comment: So I am not sure if this would work, because I am checking the current page at the layout.html.erb file itself of the layouts directory, and I only declare the @event at the events controller. But I will try, thanks.

Comment: worked without the id, thanks very much, I was trying something similar except I had action as method, my mistake